# Is there any share kit for ios

Tags: iphone, sharing, sharekit

Do you know about any sharing kit specified for such sport apps, like Runkeeper, Mapmyfitness, Strava, Nike+, Training peaks..?

I know about huge library, [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit), but there is nothing I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what exactly do you want to share, but I think the answer is no.

Assuming you want to share a tracked route for example, the app would need to have some kind of an URL scheme to be called upon to pass the data. My guess is that all of them use the same data, but with a different model making it pretty hard to accept the data not generated in the app, and generally, not worth the time since there is no real benefit for them if the users use a different application.

There's a useful list of URL schemes here:
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes